# Garbage collection in java "re assigned"

Tags: java, object

Can we quickly re-assign a handle to object that has no handle in memory before it becomes a candidate for garbage collection?

Can anyone explain to me please? How can it be done if possible.

Comment: What language/runtime are w talking about? How would you find the "lose object"?

Comment: Check again... I have re phrased the question

Comment: look at soft- or weakreferences

Comment: If it "has no handle in memory," there's no way to assign a handle to it; nothing's pointing to it, so where else would you get a pointer to it?  No, this isn't possible; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: But I think it make sense to reassign a handle to it since its still there in memory...